# Your Command Line Tools (CLT) does not support macOS 13

Tags: macos, homebrew, command-line-tool, macos-ventura

I am using MacOS Ventura 13.0, and here CLT does not support.
I am facing this issue during installing heroku cli using brew.

I tried to resolve this issue using the suggestions, but not working.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no new version of XCode and CLT to support Ventura 13.0 in AppStore.
I have resolved this issue by installing XCode 14.1 and CLT for XCode 14.1 manually. They are all beta versions, and not published on AppStore.

I downloaded them by manually using following links:
XCode 14.1 :
https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_14.1_Release_Candidate_2/Xcode_14.1_Release_Candidate_2.xip

CLT :
https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_14.1_Release_Candidate_2/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_14.1_Release_Candidate_2.dmg

Answer (score 0):

I found that entering the following commands from the error message worked for me:

`sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

`sudo xcode-select --install`